# Como fazer uma aplicação ASP.NET Core MVC para português?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, português-do-brasil

Eu gostaria de poder fazer uma aplicação em português. Já fazia isso com o ASP.NET MVC 5 de uma forma super simples através de uma instalação NuGet.

Porém não achei nada parecido para a versão CORE. Já utilizei a configuração:

```
        var supportedCultures = new[] {
            new CultureInfo("pt-BR")
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt-BR"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
```

para tratar os *requests* localizados em português, mas as mensagens de erros automáticas ainda estão em inglês:

> The Descrição field is required.

Como posso configurar minha aplicação para português?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para localizar as mensagens de erro você precisa adicionar outro serviço: AddDataAnnotationsLocalization.

Exemplo:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```

No caso de cima, é usado um Resource seguindo o caminho *\Resources\Caminho\Do\Model.resx*

**Model**

```
[Display(Name = "Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

**Resource**

```
Name: Name
Value: Nome

Name: Required
Value: O campo {0} é obrigatório.
```